# Prove that the equation has no solution

Tags: analysis

Prove that there exist infinitely many positive real numbers $r$ such that the equation
$2^x +3^y + 5^z = r$ has no solution $(x, y, z) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q}$.

First, I prove that set $S = \{\, 2^x +3^y + 5^z: (x, y, z) \subseteq \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \times \mathbb{Q} \,\}$ is countable; is it correct? Then what is the next step to the proof?

Answer (score 1):

Any number not in your set $S$ is a real number $r$ that you're looking for. Can you establish that there are infinitely many real numbers not in $S$, once you know that $S$ is countable?

In fact, every number in your set $S$ is algebraic, and the algebraic numbers are a countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$. Any transcendental number would work as $r$, so if you produce infinitely many of those, you're done.